# Php writing in file

Tags: php, file, iostream

I have this code:

```
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'crawl.txt', 'w+');
$time1 = microtime(true);
......
$time2 = microtime(true);
$time = $time2-$time1;
$text = "Training id: ".$this->realIdTraining." Time: ".$time."\r\n";
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
sleep(5);
```

I catch this error: `Warning: fwrite(): 120 is not a valid stream resource`

Any ideas what can I do?

Guys: Have to add that first row written correctly.(!!!)

Comment: looks like your fopen failed. Probaly because you dont have write permission in that directory

Comment: You need to test `if ($file){....}` after the `fopen()` call.

Comment: Mmmm. Read my addition please. "Have to add that first row written correctly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, if the code beetween ... and $this->realIdTraining exists somewhere

Also, verify first if the file exists , and others, like write permissions, if needed.

```
<?php

$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/crawl.txt', 'w+');
$time1 = microtime(true);
...
$time2 = microtime(true);
$time = $time2-$time1;
$text = "Training id: ".($this->realIdTraining)." Time: ".$time."\r\n";
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
sleep(5);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

test for permission to open the file for writing

```
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/crawl.txt', 'w+');
if(!$file)
{
     echo 'cannot write to file';
}
else
{
    $time1 = microtime(true);
    ...
    $time2 = microtime(true);
    $time = $time2-$time1;
    $text = "Training id: ".$this->realIdTraining." Time: ".$time."\r\n";
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fclose($file);
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian How so? It is different to your code, and addresses the comment he made before anyone else on this quesition.

Comment: I did do the ($this->realIdTraining) as I pasted @IonutFlaviusPogacian code not OP. Removed brackets as not necessary

Comment: @Fluffeh 5 minutes ago, 3 minutes ago; :)) its ok, we are here to help and learn